# complexity/runtime of pseudocode using big-O notation

Tags: pseudocode

I need a little help with a problem. I just started reading about O-notation but I'm still new when it comes to analysing code.

So here's the problem:

The following pseudocode is given, where A is a number field whose elements over the indices 1 to length(A) can be accessed. i is made up of whole numbers so the results of the division are rounded down. What's the complexity of the function SkipPrint?

```
1: procedure SkipPrint(A)
2:      i <- length(A)
3:          do
4:             print(A[i])
5:                 i <- i/2
6:                   while i>0
```

So I think the complexity O(n) since the function needs to go through the array but only once, right? (line 2) Every other line is of lesser magnitude so it stays O(n)?

Thanks in advance. Your help is appreciated.

Salute

Answer (score 0):

This would be O(n), yes. You are correct. This is because there is a single loop that iterates in one direction. (`i` always get smaller in this case)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say `n = length(A)` and assume first that we are in the simpler case where `length(A) = 2^m`, for some integer `m`.

Then `i`, being halved at every step, would have the values:

```
2^m, 2^{m-1}, 2^{m-2}, ..., 2, 1, 0
```

which shows that the loop will run `m` times until `i` reaches `0`. Since `n = 2^m`, this means that `m = lg n` and therefore the complexity is `O(lg n)`.

In the general case, define `m := floor(lg n)`. The analysis above shows that the loop will iterate `m` times until `i` becomes `0`. Thus, the complexity would be `O(floor(lg n))`, which is the same as `O(lg n)`.